# Large Zip file is corrupted on 32 bit JDK

Tags: zip

We are creating single Zip file from multiple files using ZipOutputStream (on 32 bit jdk).

If we create Zip file using 5 pdf files(each pdf is of 1 GB) than it creates corrupt Zip file. If I create Zip file using (4 pdf files - each pdf is of 1 GB) than it creates correct Zip file.

Is there any limitation in Zip file size on 32 bit JDK?

Comment: You'll have to use Java 7 (see my answer)

Answer (score 2):

The original ZIP format had a number of limits (uncompressed size of a file, compressed size of a file and total size of the archive) at 4GB.

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)

The original zip format had a 4 GiB limit on various things (uncompressed size of a file, compressed size of a file and total size of the archive), as well as a limit of 65535 entries in a zip archive. In version 4.5 of the specification (which is not the same as v4.5 of any particular tool), PKWARE introduced the "ZIP64" format extensions to get around these limitations, increasing the limitation to 16 EiB (264 bytes).
The File Explorer in Windows XP does not support ZIP64, but the Explorer in Windows Vista does. Likewise, some libraries, such as DotNetZip and IO::Compress::Zip in Perl, support ZIP64. Java's built-in java.util.zip supports ZIP64 from version Java 7.[29]